# how to get only the group members of an specific OU and move/migrate to a destination group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

i need to get all group members which are in a specific OU (usersNewYork), the location of the group is in an other ou (ProxyGroups).

To copy the Users from the Group i would use this script:

```
Add-ADGroupMember destinationgroup -Members (Get-ADGroupMember sourceGroup)
```

How is it possible to only copy the members to the Destination Group from the specific OU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter your results to only include the group members that you want.  There are several ways to do that, but you could try something like this:

```
Add-ADGroupMember destinationgroup -Members (Get-ADGroupMember sourceGroup | ? dn -match "*OU=usersNewYork,dc=company,dc=com" )
```